# Plotly fig.show keeps Python alive

Tags: python, plotly

I've just written this up into a `.py` (not notebook) Python file: https://github.com/bkontonis/Plot-PostCodes-on-Interactive-Map-Using-Python/blob/master/Plot%20on%20Map.ipynb

The main and final output is

```py
fig = px.scatter_mapbox(post_df, lat="latitude", lon="longitude", zoom=3, height=300)
fig.update_layout(mapbox_style="open-street-map")
fig.update_layout(margin={"r":0,"t":0,"l":0,"b":0})
fig.show()
```

When I run `python myscript.py` my browser is opened to `http://127.0.0.1:64923`, then the Python process running in the console immediately exits. There are no `jobs`.

However, especially if I run this a few times in a row, there are still `python3.11` processes running on my machine, consuming as much CPU as they can each.

I would prefer that no child process is spawned (if that is what is happening) and I can use `ctrl-c` later in my console to quit all Python processes that `python myscript.py` kickstarted, or I need some other way to work around Python exiting-but-not-exiting after `fig.show()`

Comment: This [reference](https://plotly.com/python/renderers/) may help. Please take a look.

Comment: @r-beginners I had read that just before posting the question, but I don't see what I'm meant to be able to take from it to fix my problem

Comment: I cannot reproduce this on my machine (Windows 10), the python process always immediatly closes after a new tab has been opened in my browser, and no "left-over" processes are running after multiple executions. What OS are you using?